# WKWebView fails loading iframe: WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=7, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=-999, isMainFrame=0

Tags: swift, loading, wkwebview

WkWebview is not loading iframe and throw an error with code -999. I read and found this error occurs when the past request is cancelled but it happens every-time.
Tried code from below link:

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_iframe

Here is the code in mobile app:

```
let html:String = "<html><body><h1>The iframe element</h1><iframe src=\"https://www.w3schools.com\" title=\"W3Schools Free Online Web Tutorials\"></iframe></body></html>"
 
reloadWebKit(stringHTML: html)



func reloadWebKit(stringHTML:String){
        wkWebView.loadHTMLString(stringHTML, baseURL: nil)
        wkWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
```

Comment: Any solution you found for above issue ?